# IndexOutOfBoundsException...know what the error means but need help debugging?

Tags: java

Creating a program to generate random numbers and put them in either an even or odd array, but get the same error message above? If anyone knows how to format better please help!

```
    import static java.lang.Math.*;
    import java.util.Random;


    public class Unit8
    {
public static void main ( String [ ] args )
{   
    int [ ] randomNum = new int [100] ;

    for ( int x = 0; x <= randomNum.length; x++ )
    {
        randomNum [ x ] =  (int) (Math.random ( ) * 25 ); 
    }
    int sum = 0;
    int [ ] oddArray = new int [ 100 ] ;
    for ( int x = 0; x <= randomNum.length; x++ )
    {
        if (randomNum [ x ] % 2 != 0 )
            sum += oddArray [ x ];      

    }
    int sum2 = 0;
    int [ ] evenArray = new int [ 100 ] ;
    for ( int x = 0; x <= randomNum.length; x++ )
    {
        if (randomNum [ x ] % 2 == 0 )
            sum2 += evenArray [ x ] ; 
    }
    display ( oddArray );
    display1 ( evenArray );

}
public static void display ( int [ ] oddArray)
{
    System.out.println ( oddArray );
}
public static void display1 ( int [ ] evenArray )
{
    System.out.println ( evenArray );
}
    }
```

Comment: If you know what the error means, why do you need help to debug it?

Answer (score 4):

Your *for loops* are the culprits. The condition should not have `<=`, rather just `<`.

Replace: -

```
for ( int x = 0; x <= randomNum.length; x++ )
```

with: -

```
for ( int x = 0; x < randomNum.length; x++ )
```

Because you don't want to access the index - `randomNum.length`, as it will be `OutOfBounds`.

Answer (score 1):

This line is causing error

```
 for ( int x = 0; x <= randomNum.length; x++ )
```

In java array indexes start from 0, the array randomNum has indexes from 0 to 99. The randomNum.length returns the number of elements the array can hold which will be 100 .

By doing  `x <= randomNum.length;`

In the for loop you are trying to access 101th(randomNum[100]) element in the array; Which is not present, Hence the Exception

So replace the for loop to contain `for ( int x = 0; x < randomNum.length; x++ )`

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is here:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= randomNum.length; x++) {
```

you should change it to:

```
for (int x = 0; x < randomNum.length; x++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using <= randomNum.length in your loops, which will go from 0 to 100.
your array randomNum does start it 0, but it has only 100 spaces: it goes from 0 to 99

Change your loops to: -

```
for (int x = 0; x < randomNum.length; x++) {
```

Lookin furher, in your "display" functions you'll only get an address, you must do

```
public static void display(int[] oddArray) {
    for(int i=0; i<oddArray.length;i++)
        System.out.println(oddArray[i]);
}
```

Looking EVEN FURTHER, your functionality is all messed up, you're never filling your oddArray and evenArray. Also, you don't need three loops, you can do all in one.

I assume this is a homework so I won't give you a full working code, but good luck

Comment: when I put that code in I get weird symbols and numbers? How do I fill them (I'm a java noob).

Comment: The "weird symbols" you are getting are from your second display function (display1), you must fix it as well. The "weird symbols" are memory locations, because you are printing the array instead of each element separately. The array doesn't have a toString() method, that's why it's printing the memory pos

Answer (score 0):

Here's your bug:

```
for ( int x = 0; x <= randomNum.length; x++ )
```

It should be

```
for ( int x = 0; x < randomNum.length; x++ )
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time to debug, just put a breakpoint on your loop(s) and run it in debug mode. Then you can check values as you run it line by line.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same fix as everyone else. However, I also noticed that you were printing out 2 arrays that only included the number 0. You weren't using the random numbers at all to update the even or odd arrays. Also, the two display methods are identical. You don't need a separate method for each since you can use the display method to print out both arrays. This also applies to variables as well. You can reuse the same variable as long as you are no longer using it (Like the `index` variable in the code I wrote). I updated the code to simplify it, as well as fix all of the errors you had as follows:

```
public class PrintOddAndEvenArrays {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] randomNum = new int[500];

    for (int x = 0; x < randomNum.length; x++) {
        randomNum[x] = (int) (Math.random() * 25);
    }
    int index = 0;
    int[] oddArray = new int[100];
    for (int x = 0; x < randomNum.length; x++) {
        if(index == 100){
            break;
        }
        if (randomNum[x] % 2 != 0){
            oddArray[index] = randomNum[x];
            index++;
        }
    }
    index = 0;
    int[] evenArray = new int[100];
    for (int x = 0; x < randomNum.length; x++) {
        if(index == 100){
            break;
        }
        if (randomNum[x] % 2 == 0){
            evenArray[index] = randomNum[x];
            index++;
        }
    }
    display(oddArray);
    display(evenArray);

}

public static void display(int[] Array) {
    for(int a = 0; a < Array.length-1;a++){
        System.out.print(Array[a]+ ", ");
        if(a == Array.length-2){
            System.out.print(Array[a+1]);
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}

}
```

For future reference, to debug by yourself, the error printed out in the console usually tells you what line to reference to fix the error. Start by learning what the error is and how to fix it. Usually a quick Google search allows you to understand the error and how you can fix it. Then, once you can run the program, check your output with the desired output and make changes accordingly. With more complex errors, you'll have to debug by yourself, since the code will be a lot longer and more difficult for someone else to understand. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm swamped in this online course that I'm struggling with and your feedback is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Also, to simplify coding if you haven't already, try downloading [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) or [netbeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/). An ide makes coding a lot easier.